# Community doesn't poke questions that are truly unanswered?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, community-user

I've been going around the unanswered sections of my network, and am I right in assuming that Community doesn't poke questions with 0 answers?

Whatever the answer is, can I get an explanation of what I'm seeing?

Comment: to avoid another click: `The Community user will bump non-negatively scored questions that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that.`

Comment: Note to close-voters: The OP has **completely changed their original question**.

Comment: ... Uh ... Should I undo that, and make a new question? I know it usually isn't allowed, but I thought, since there were no answers... ... *Paranoia*

Comment: You *should* have made a new question, *especially* when there are pending close votes. I don't think there's any point now though. It's up to you - you can either roll back and allow this question to be closed and make a new question with your new question or just wait and see as to what happens (hopefully nothing)...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ question is closed now.  And AlE rolled back the edit so the duplicate closure make sense.

Comment: I disagree with @AlE rollback. As long as the question doesn't have any answers that would be turned pointless, OP has full right to change it into whatever he/she wants.

Comment: ..../cc @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ ^